# Capturing, forging and injecting packets

Tags: capture, packet, packet-capture, inject, packet-injection

In order to build a measurement tool, I need to capture packets, forge them and re-inject them into the network. What are some tools or libraries that I could look into?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [libcrafter](http://code.google.com/p/libcrafter/). Seems very easy to use! The library is able to craft or decode packets of most common networks protocols, send them on the wire, capture them and match requests and replies.

Answer (score 2):

You can use libcap http://wiki.wireshark.org/libpcap to capture packets. libdnet can be a choice for packet forging http://libdnet.sourceforge.net/